# Apache - allow malformed headers for backwards compatibility by adjusting error strictness?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

We moved a site from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 (same PHP version) and now code that used to work is getting a 500 error due to `[core:error] [pid ######] [client ##.##.##.##:#####] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header:`

We identified the issue in the code which sent a bad header and can fix it, but if we wanted legacy code not to break if there are other occurrences buried on various sites that we plan to move, is there some way to tell Apache not to fail on this?  Like can we lower the strictness of errors it cares about or something?

Answer (score 1):

This question is old however it may help others. 
You need to look for

```
HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe
```

The defualt is Strict but changing it to Unsafe will allow malformed headers but its also considered Unsafe though.

This needs to go into httpd.conf 
eg. on centos it goes /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf